# Principled Shader inputs

Tags: python, shaders

I am looking for documentation on the titled item. Of course, I first went to the [Blender 2.79 API documentation](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.ShaderNodeBsdfPrincipled.html?highlight=principled#bpy.types.ShaderNodeBsdfPrincipled) to find out about the node inputs and their acceptable values, but couldn't sort out how to determine default values for a given input from that page. I've searched on here for the titled item and got 16 answers, none of which addressed my problem. Please allow me to illustrate using a code snippet from a class that creates a shader in a material zone of a figure.

```
  def buildShaderset(self, image):
    if self.selSdr == "PrinSSS":
      self.matOut = self.treeNodes.nodes.new("ShaderNodeOutputMaterial")
      self.matOut.location = (100, 450)
      self.nodes["Output"] = self.matOut

      if (self.Region[0:4] == 'Skin' or self.Region == 'Mouth'):
        self.shPrin = self.treeNodes.nodes.new("ShaderNodeBsdfPrincipled")
        self.shPrin.location = (100, 250)
        self.nodes["Principled"] = self.shPrin
        self.treeNodes.links.new(self.shPrin.outputs[0], self.matOut.inputs[0])
        # Specular values
        self.shPrin.inputs[5].default_value = .015
        self.shPrin.inputs[11].default_value = .2
        self.shPrin.inputs[14].default_value = 1.8

    # Skin and Eyes mat slot names have _suffixes
    if self.Region[0:4] == 'Skin':
      self.makeSkin()
```

...etc

I sort-of guessed the input[] locations for spec values, which appear to reflect on the created node. I was wondering if there was documentation on those inputs for Python developers (of which I am least).

Thank you for considering my little conundrum.

Answer (score 4):

Just ignore the input list index values. Treat the input list as a dictionary.

```
shPrin.inputs['Specular'].default_value = 0.015
shPrin.inputs['Sheen Tint'].default_value = 0.2
shPrin.inputs['IOR'].default_value = 1.8
```

If you know an index and want to know the name -

```
>>> shPrin.inputs[11].name
'Sheen Tint'
```

And to list all the available names -

```
for i in shPrin.inputs:
    print(i.name)
```

Answer (score 3):

From 2.79 source code, there is this definition. I guess the inputs are in the order you want here:

```
static bNodeSocketTemplate sh_node_bsdf_principled_in[] = {
    {   SOCK_RGBA, 1, N_("Base Color"),             0.8f, 0.8f, 0.8f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f},
    {   SOCK_FLOAT, 1, N_("Subsurface"),            0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, PROP_FACTOR},
    {   SOCK_VECTOR, 1, N_("Subsurface Radius"),    1.0f, 0.2f, 0.1f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 100.0f},
    {   SOCK_RGBA, 1, N_("Subsurface Color"),       0.8f, 0.8f, 0.8f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f},
    {   SOCK_FLOAT, 1, N_("Metallic"),              0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, PROP_FACTOR},
    {   SOCK_FLOAT, 1, N_("Specular"),              0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, PROP_FACTOR},
    {   SOCK_FLOAT, 1, N_("Specular Tint"),         0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, PROP_FACTOR},
    {   SOCK_FLOAT, 1, N_("Roughness"),             0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, PROP_FACTOR},
    {   SOCK_FLOAT, 1, N_("Anisotropic"),           0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, PROP_FACTOR},
    {   SOCK_FLOAT, 1, N_("Anisotropic Rotation"),  0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, PROP_FACTOR},
    {   SOCK_FLOAT, 1, N_("Sheen"),                 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, PROP_FACTOR},
    {   SOCK_FLOAT, 1, N_("Sheen Tint"),            0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, PROP_FACTOR},
    {   SOCK_FLOAT, 1, N_("Clearcoat"),             0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, PROP_FACTOR},
    {   SOCK_FLOAT, 1, N_("Clearcoat Roughness"),   0.03f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, PROP_FACTOR},
    {   SOCK_FLOAT, 1, N_("IOR"),                   1.45f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1000.0f},
    {   SOCK_FLOAT, 1, N_("Transmission"),          0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, PROP_FACTOR},
    {   SOCK_FLOAT, 1, N_("Transmission Roughness"),0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, PROP_FACTOR},
    {   SOCK_VECTOR, 1, N_("Normal"),               0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f, PROP_NONE, SOCK_HIDE_VALUE},
    {   SOCK_VECTOR, 1, N_("Clearcoat Normal"),     0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f, PROP_NONE, SOCK_HIDE_VALUE},
    {   SOCK_VECTOR, 1, N_("Tangent"),              0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f, PROP_NONE, SOCK_HIDE_VALUE},
    {   -1, 0, ""   }
};
```

Comment: That answered more than one question: about this specific shader node, and about nodes in general. Sock_Vector takes a tuple. And counting of inputs starts at 0?

Comment: afaik, yes 0 based. I don't know the code in details, but that'd be counter intuitive the inputs in C and Python be in a different order.

Comment: @lemon Please could you include a link to that code? I'm having trouble finding it.

Comment: @RobinBetts it is in "blender\source\blender\nodes\shader\nodes\node_shader_bsdf_principled.c" line 32 from the 2.79.4 (current) version